# WCF Performance : Connection to WCF Service takes long time

Tags: c#, .net, performance, wcf, entity-framework

I have a WCF service hosted on IIS 7.5 on my server. I have used Entity framework 5.0 in my service.

When I call that service from my local system by adding service reference and creating client in a site, it takes approx 40 seconds to get the response. I tried calling the same service which is on my local and here it takes only 3-4 seconds.

After adding reference to the service which is on server to the site which is on local system, the binding and endpoint added in web config looks like:

```
<binding name="WSHttpBinding_IMyWCFService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:50:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
          bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
          allowCookies="false">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
            enabled="false" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" />
          </security>
        </binding>




<endpoint address="https://<url>/MyWCFService.svc/soap"
        binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IMyWCFService"
        contract="MerchantService.IMyWCFService" name="WSHttpBinding_IMyWCFService" />
```

first I thought that it is a issue of Entity framework. But then i checked the execution time of the method using Entity framework profiler. Its hardly taking 1 second.

also when i call the service, it requires to add a header, which I am adding.

So, where it is taking that 40 seconds time. And its not slow startup or taking time only for first time. It takes this much time always.

Is network speed can be a cause to this delay. If yes, up to what extent?

The service returns a list List. Could it be a problem, that we should not return Lists. What can be the alternative?

Also, does Entity framework establishes connection to DB every time a request comes and if the Database connection is taking time. Can it be possible?

Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I was using Code first approach. And to improve performance, i tried to pre-generate views so that the overhead of generating view for the first time can be reduced. But I think the views were not working.
So, I tried switching to Database First approach and then i generated views and uploaded that build to remote server. Now the time reduced to 10 seconds from 40 seconds. Also I tried opening the DB connection at WCF service start up. And it again reduced the time to 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to isolate the issue step by step

1) To find out if network bandwidth is the issue, just host a simple service returning some simple value like integer or string and check its response time.

2) If response time in Step 1 is drastically improved, then look into the database or list issue.

Comment: Hi Deepansh, Thanks for reply. The network may be a problem for increased time, but then in fastest n/w I can test my services, I found out the time was 25 seconds. I found out that the problem was with EF. Please see the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your problem is credential negotiation. There is an easy way to verify this, just run the service on the same server without security (if this is permissible.)

One possible remedy is to eliminate the SOAP credential negotiation by setting the negotiateServiceCredential attribute to false. You'll need to make sure that Kerberos is enabled for your domain first.

Comment: Hi Paul. The problem was with EF. Please see my answer. Thanks for reply.